# Justify Paragraph Text HTML

Tags: html, css

How would one justify this text??
I have tried and searched for days to get something so simple to work..

Ex:

HTML:

```
<div id="justify">
   <p>I just want this to justify..</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#justify {
    width: 100%;
    background: #D33;
}

#justify p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    list-style: disc outside none;
    text-align: justify;
    display: list-item;
    background: #ccc;
    }
```

Here on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xDqwF/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Define “justify”. Justification of paragraphs is generally defined only in terms of filling all lines except the last line up to the available width. You seem to want to fill the last and only line too, and should say that in the question (preferably even in the title).

Comment: I'd like to fill an entire line (or only line - i guess you'd call it last too).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#justify p:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Through some HTML Trickery, this should work. I found it on a blog post ages ago when I had a similar problem. Check it out on the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xDqwF/2/

Comment: my only problem with this is the space beneath that it adds. is it possible to remove it?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this works good. The question above about removing the white space is not possible because it's what helps the last line appear justified. Normally if you are using a <p> tag you would expect a line break after each paragraph. You could use overflow: hidden and set a height to hide it.

Answer (score 3):

That's simple, put the text in a `<p>` an edit this in CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <p id="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.ultricies n.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.ultricies n.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    height:200px;
    width:350px;
}

#justify {      
    text-align: justify;
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xDqwF/3/).

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .justify {
                text-align: justify;
                text-justify: inter-word;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="justify">
            <p>This is justified</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

According W3C school text-justify is only supported on IE, but on that since IE 5.5

text-align can specify justification, as mentioned above, but some cautions:

- In all browsers I've checked justification is handled by increasing interword spacing. The typical amount of surplus space is 2-4 characters.  Divided up on a typical line of 10 words or so, this looks tolerably ok.
- On lines with fewer words the surplus space has be absorbed in fewer spaces.  The result is large gaps.  This is a problem in multi-column layouts, or captions under portrait oriented pictures.

FWIW on a good DTP program, the space for justifying is split between the inter-word spaces, and the inter letter spacing.  Good fonts have in internal table of *kerning* hints to control this spacing.  (You can't put as much space between "Y" and "o" as you can between "m" and "n" without it looking odd.)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend "W3C school" as a source of information